# No ID when posting to multiple tables in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to post data to two different tables in my application.  These tables are as follows.

Table A

```
the_vessel
vessel_idx        int 
vessel_name       varchar
vessel_imono      decimal
```

Table B

```
the_vessel_spec
vessel_spec_idx   int
vessel_parent_id  int
vessel_bhp        decimal
```

You'll noticed in Table B that there is a column called "vessel_parent_id" this is to hold the PK "vessel_idx" from "the_vessel" so that the data can be related.

The problem that I am having is that when I post the data the ID from "vessel_idx" in Table A is not being posted to Table B "vessel_parent_id".  I had this working previously but for some reason it's refusing to work now and I need some help.  Perhaps my approach is wrong or there are considerations I've not made.

Here is my create method in the controller for the above tables.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(FullVesselViewModel model)
{
    var the_vessel = new tbl_vessels
    {
        vessel_name = model.vessel_name,
        vessel_imono = model.vessel_imono
    };
    var the_vessel_spec = new tbl_vessel_spec
    {
        vessel_bhp = model.vessel_bhp
        parent_id = model.vessel_idx
    };
    using (var context = new seabrokersEntities())
    {
        context.tbl_vessels.Add(the_vessel);
        the_vessel_spec.vessel_spec_idx = the_vessel.vessel_idx;
        context.tbl_vessel_spec.Add(the_vessel_spec);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
     return View("Index");
}
```

Here is the ViewModel I created for this as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MyProject.Models;

namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class FullVesselViewModel
    { 
        public int parent_id { get; set; }
        public int vessel_idx { get; set; }
        public string vessel_name { get; set; }
        public string vessel_imono { get; set; }
        public decimal vessel_bhp { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are use EF, so in order to represent relationship between entities, you should use navigation properties. It will be much easier for you.

Regarding your case, you should write as below

```
public class tbl_vessels {
    [Key]
    public int vessel_idx { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    public IList<the_vessel_spec>  the_vessel_specs { get; set; }
}

public class the_vessel_spec {
    [Key]
    public int vessel_spec_idx { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("vessel_parent")]
    public int vessel_parent_id { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    public tbl_vessels vessel_parent { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(FullVesselViewModel model)
{
    var the_vessel = new tbl_vessels
    {
        //vessel_name = model.vessel_name,
        //vessel_imono = model.vessel_imono,

        the_vessel_specs = new List {
            new tbl_vessel_spec
            {
                //vessel_bhp = model.vessel_bhp
                //parent_id = model.vessel_idx
            }
        }
    };

    using (var context = new seabrokersEntities())
    {
        context.tbl_vessels.Add(the_vessel);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
     return View("Index");
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the replies.  I discovered that the reason for the index value of zero was down to the lack of relationship between the tables, implementing this relationship caused the code to work as expected.